# Find min in Arraylist of object, can't compare the elements in an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, min

I'm trying to invoke the `getScore()` method in my `StudentScore` class to determine the min and max over elements in an `ArrayList`, within the `printStat()` method presented below.  I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.  What does that mean, and how can I fix the problem?

```
public class ScoreCalculator{
    private int[] scoreCounter;
    ArrayList<StudentScore> scores ;

    public ScoreCalculator(int maxScore) {
        scoreCounter = new int[maxScore];
        scores = new ArrayList<StudentScore>(maxScore); 
    }

    public void printStat() {
        System.out.println("Score Report for " + scores.size() + " Students ");

        min = 0;
        max = 0;
        int j=0;

        for ( j = 0; j < scores.size(); j++) {

            if (scores.get(j).getScore() < scores.get(j - 1).getScore()) {
                min = scores.get(j).getScore();
            } 
            if (scores.get(j).getScore() > scores.get(j - 1).getScore()) {
                max = scores.get(j).getScore();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(max);

    }
```

Comment: `j-1` can be negative in your code, index range is 0 to size() -1, negative value is not allowed

Comment: You access at element `j-1`. I suggest you to order your list, so the first one element is the `min` and the last one the `max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loop starts form `j=0`, and you access the element at `j-1` in the list, you will see where the issue is.

When `j=0`, you try to access `-1`. There is no index -1. Hence the error. Starting from `j=1` solves this.

Does this help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

please,

change from

```
for(j=0;j<scores.size();j++){
```

to

```
for(j=1;j<scores.size();j++){
```

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* find the min/max of a sequence by only comparing *neighboring* values.
You have to compare values to the min/max-so-far.

```
if (scores.isEmpty())
    throw new IllegalStateException("No scores found");
int min = scores.get(0).getScore();
int max = min;
for (int j = 1; j < scores.size(); j++) {
    int score = scores.get(j).getScore();
    if (score < min)
        min = score;
    if (score > max)
        max = score;
}
```